# Proof $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n>2$ for positive $n$

Tags: inequality

I would like to see some proofs that $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n>2$ for $n\in\mathbb R^+$ have some experience with inequalities, but I don't know too much theory.

Regards

Comment: Look up Bernoullis inequality!

Comment: you can just use binomial theorem...

Comment: (and Bernoulli follows from that)

Comment: Expand $(1+\frac1n)^n$ by the binomial theorem; then observe that the first two terms give $2$ and the remaining terms are positive.

Comment: @AndreasBlass woops, I think I failed hard today, thanks

Comment: The inequality is not true $0< n \leq 1$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequality fails to be true for real numbers $n$ in the interval $(0,1]$

However if you remove that condition and require $n>1\wedge n\in \mathbb{N}$

Then using the binomial theorem:
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}=\binom{n}{0}\frac{1}{n^0}+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}>2$$

Comment: What if $n$ is not a natural number?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate technique for arbitrary $n$:

$$[(1+1/n)^{n}]' = \log(1+1/n)\cdot(1+1/n)^{n} + n\cdot(1+1/n)^{n-1}\cdot (-1/n^2) \\
\geq \log(1+1/n)\cdot (1+1/n) - 1/n.$$

Now, consider $f(x) = \log(x+1)(x+1) - x$. Then, $f'(x) = \log(x+1) + 1 - 1 = \log(x+1) > 0$, $\forall x>0$.

Also, $f(0) = 0$. Hence, $f(x) > 0$, $\forall x>0$. So, in particular, our derivative is positive.

Now, evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0^{+}} (1+1/n)^{n}$, where $\frac{[\log(1+1/n)]'}{-1/n^2} = \frac{1}{1+1/n} \rightarrow 0$, whence $(1+1/n)^n > 1$.

But consider $n=1/2$. Then $(1+1/(1/2))^{1/2} = 3^{1/2} < 2$. If you assume $n\geq 1$, then, indeed, the value must be greater than or equal to $2$.